# What is this descent figure?

Tags: identify-this-game, descent

I was wandering around on boardgamegeek and I saw this picture of a guy painting Descent figures, but the post doesn't exists anymore - *thank you google* - and the figures are just amazing

I'm not sure this is descent figure, but photos are taken on Descent v2 tiles so I guess it may be an extension I don't know.

[image: descent dragons ?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the Ice Wyrm, from Descent second edition.